# Get back position in X11 in OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, xorg, xterm

I use Mac OSX. When launch X11 this open a xterm.
how I can automatically locate xterm in a specific position every time I open X11? (centered on the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defaults write org.x.X11 app_to_run "/usr/X11/bin/xterm -geometry +100+100"
```

adjusting the `+100+100` as needed to center, and using something like `100x30+100+100` to adjust size as well as position.

Comment: but, if when launch X11 open a xterm, with you command, now X11 launch  two xterms?

Comment: I try modify the last line of /usr/X11/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc file   
of   
exec xterm -geometry 140x22+0+0 -name login  
to  
exec xterm -geometry 140x22+210+0 -name login  

but not works.

Comment: you're right, the solution is: defaults write org.x.X11 app_to_run "/usr/X11/bin/xterm -geometry 140x22+210+0"